# Youtube mobile version issues in android

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I a developing a webview based android app.  I loaded youtube inside a webview in the app
.The color scheme of youtube is a black one .
But in android's default browser,the color scheme is white.Why is this  different?.I have tried setting same useragent as that of default browser.But still no difference.Why is this happening?.Anybody knows the exact url of the white version of youtube ?

I am attaching the screenshots of both

[image: Youtube in default browser] [image: Youtube in webview]

---------Sorry for the non programming related question ;)---------

Answer (score 1):

The second screenshot appears to be directly from the app. I would read up a little on Intents and Sharing on the Android dev site. If you were testing on different devices with different screen sizes the mobile responsive stuff may have slightly different themes. Then again it's youtube, they change their layouts by the minute ;)